Needing to send emails to different email addresses based on conditions or inputs into a google form
I am needing to send emails via Appscript to different people based on different conditions that were selected from one particular question on a google form. E.G. All EBO selections sent to email addy 1, all non-EBO selections sent to email addy 2, and then all selections sent to email addy 3. Below is what I have, but no matter what option is selected on the form, it only sends the email per the first if statement.
function variedEmails() {
  var aSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//Take the last row. Row is converted to string and put into an array
  var lastSheet = aSheet.getSheetValues(aSheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, aSheet.getLastColumn());

  var lastString = lastSheet.toString();
  var data = lastString.split(",");

//Take the first column (header values). Row is converted to string and put into an array 
  var headerSheet = aSheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, 1, aSheet.getLastColumn());

  var headerString = headerSheet.toString();
  var headers = headerString.split(",");

//omit the time and Timezone from timestamps in form
  var dateTime = data[0].split(" ");
  var dateTime1 = data[9].split(" ");

  data[0] = dateTime[0] + " " + dateTime[1] + " " + dateTime[2] +  " " + dateTime[3];
  data[9] = dateTime1[0] + " " + dateTime1[1] + " " + dateTime1[2] +  " " + dateTime1[3];

//string to build an HTML table 
  var table = "<table style='border: 1px solid border-collapse: collapse'>";

  for( var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++ ) {
//determine if cell is blank, and only add data if data exists for that cell
    if( data[i] != "" ) {
      table += "<tr style='border: 1px solid'><td style='border: 1px solid'>"+ headers[i] + "</td><td style='border: 1px solid'>" + data[i] + "</td></tr>";
    }
  }

  table += "</table>";

  if(data[4] == "Increase Usage Priority (Ex: EBO)"){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "emailaddy1@test.com",
    subject: "Usage Priority - Mass Change Request Form Response",
    htmlBody: table, noReply: true
    })

    if(data[4] != "Increase Usage Priority (Ex: EBO)"){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "emailaddy2@test.com",
    subject: "Mass Change Request Form Response",
    htmlBody: table, noReply: true
  })

    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "emailaddy3@test.com",
    subject: "All - Mass Change Request Form Response",
    htmlBody: table, noReply: true
    })
  }

}
}


I was actually able to figure this out after staring at it for an hour. I had some closing brackets in the wrong locations, which caused the if statements to get nested within each other, instead of letting the script read each if statement individually. The correct code is as follows:
  if(data[4] == "Increase Usage Priority (Ex: EBO)"){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "emailaddy1@test.com",
    subject: "Usage Priority - Mass Change Request Form Response",
    htmlBody: table, noReply: true
    })
  }
  if(data[4] != "Increase Usage Priority (Ex: EBO)"){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "emailaddy2@test.com",
    subject: "Mass Change Request Form Response",
    htmlBody: table, noReply: true
    })
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "emailaddy3@test.com",
  subject: "All - Mass Change Request Form Response",
  htmlBody: table, noReply: true
    })
}


MailApp.sendEmail() accepts a list of email addresses, so you can push the addresses into an array and join the array into a comma-separated list, like this:
  const isEbo = data[4] === 'Increase Usage Priority (Ex: EBO)';
  const emailAddresses = ['emailaddy3@test.com', isEbo ? 'emailaddy1@test.com' : 'emailaddy2@test.com'];
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddresses.join(','),
    subject: 'Mass Change Request Form Response',
    htmlBody: table,
    noReply: true,
  });

See Array.
